# Adding Two Formulas to One Cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need two formulas in one single cell, both doing different things, but they also rely on each other. Basically, one calculates a start time and end time, giving the hours worked. Then the second part has to subtract .50 if the hours worked are greater than 8 total hrs.

I've tried using '`AND`, `IF`, `&`' and also things I've found online, but nothing seems to work.

```
IF(C6 < D6, 0, 1)+D6 - C6 *-24 AND IF (C6 > 8, C6 - 0.5,0)
```

I've tried many different variants of this formula to no avail. Maybe I just can't combine them or maybe it isn't even possible, any help would be great!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help answerers, you could put in some more clarifying information - specifically, which cell is this formula for (presumably not C6 or D6, since that'd be self referential), which cell is the start time, and which cell is the end time?

Comment: Hey, can you share a screenshot of your spreadsheet as that would clarify the requirement better. Also, you should try to "nest" the and condition within if to achieve what you need.You may nest multiple ifs within the outer if. That is the easiest way to have more than one formulas working in the same cell.

Comment: If ( [formula] > 8, [formula] - 0.5, [formula] )

Answer (score 0):

try one of these:

```
=IF(C6 < D6, 0, 1)+D6-C6*-24-IF(C6 > 8, C6-0.5, 0)
```

---

```
=IF(C6 < D6, 0, 1)+D6-IF(C6 > 8, C6-0.5, C6)*-24
```

---

```
=IF(IF(C6 > 8, C6-0.5, C6) < D6, 0, 1)+D6-IF(C6 > 8, C6-0.5, C6)*-24
```